# change default limit of products per page in admin panel

Tags: product-grid

[image]

I tried changing default limit of product per page but its not changing. I want to change default limit from 20 to 10 without making changes in core file . And I want to do this in admin panel (Product View page) not in frontend.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Copy file :

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

To

> app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

add this protected var in this class

> protected $_defaultLimit    = 10;

Copy file

> adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml

To

> adminhtml/default/default/template/custom/grid.phtml

and set this as custom template for class

> Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid

now change per page option (add for value 10) in file

> adminhtml/default/default/template/custom/grid.phtml

```
<select name="<?php echo $this->getVarNameLimit() ?>" onchange="<?php echo $this->getJsObjectName() ?>.loadByElement(this)">
                <option value="10"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==10): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>10</option>
                <option value="20"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==20): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>20</option>
                <option value="30"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==30): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>30</option>
                <option value="50"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==50): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>50</option>
                <option value="100"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==100): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>100</option>
                <option value="200"<?php if($this->getCollection()->getPageSize()==200): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>200</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: how to set this as custom template for class??

Comment: default limit changes on sales order page but not on product page

Comment: "how to set this as custom template for class" in setTemplate in construct() function

Comment: if you can tell me how to write exactly the it will be helpfull

Comment: public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate("custom/grid.phtml");
        $this->setId('productGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setVarNameFilter('product_filter');

    }

Comment: its not working for the product page

Comment: You need to check now. i have checked this and is working fine

Comment: i want 10 as default value it is not setting that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30479/discussion-between-minesh-patel-and-donika).